# How to rename pandas dataframe columns adding an integer

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a dataframe like this:

```
        0      1       2      3      4   ...     37      38     39 40   41
0   26.265  0.072  27.925  3.011  4.541  ...  7.812  16.954  0.000  1  nan
0   26.265  0.072  27.901  3.015  4.541  ...  7.773  16.954  0.000  1  nan
0   26.265  0.072  27.925  3.011  4.541  ...  7.773  17.032  0.000  1  nan
0   26.265  0.072  27.901  3.012  4.541  ...  7.773  16.954  0.000  1  nan
0   26.265  0.072  27.901  3.015  4.541  ...  7.773  17.032  0.000  1  nan
..     ...    ...     ...    ...    ...  ...    ...     ...    ... ..  ...
0   26.241  0.072  27.901  3.013  4.541  ...  7.773  17.032  0.000  1  nan
0   26.265  0.072  27.925  3.012  4.541  ...  7.773  16.954  0.000  1  nan
0   26.265  0.073  27.901  3.012  4.541  ...  7.812  16.954  0.000  1  nan
0   26.265  0.072  27.901  3.016  4.541  ...  7.773  16.954  0.000  1  nan
0   26.265  0.072  27.901  3.012  4.541  ...  7.773  17.032  0.000  1  nan
```

i would like to rename columns adding 2 to each one obtaining:

```
        2      3       4      5      6   ...     39      40     41 42   43
0   26.265  0.072  27.925  3.011  4.541  ...  7.812  16.954  0.000  1  nan
0   26.265  0.072  27.901  3.015  4.541  ...  7.773  16.954  0.000  1  nan
0   26.265  0.072  27.925  3.011  4.541  ...  7.773  17.032  0.000  1  nan
0   26.265  0.072  27.901  3.012  4.541  ...  7.773  16.954  0.000  1  nan
0   26.265  0.072  27.901  3.015  4.541  ...  7.773  17.032  0.000  1  nan
..     ...    ...     ...    ...    ...  ...    ...     ...    ... ..  ...
0   26.241  0.072  27.901  3.013  4.541  ...  7.773  17.032  0.000  1  nan
0   26.265  0.072  27.925  3.012  4.541  ...  7.773  16.954  0.000  1  nan
0   26.265  0.073  27.901  3.012  4.541  ...  7.812  16.954  0.000  1  nan
0   26.265  0.072  27.901  3.016  4.541  ...  7.773  16.954  0.000  1  nan
0   26.265  0.072  27.901  3.012  4.541  ...  7.773  17.032  0.000  1  nan
```

i have done it in this way:

```
data.rename(columns={41:43,40:42,39:41,38:40,37:39,36:38,35:37,34:36,33:35,32:34,31:33,30:32,29:31...})
```

but i was wander where is the best code to do this

thank you

Comment: please accept one of the answers as solution by clicking the checkmark next to my answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can also work on the columns directly:

```
df.columns = df.columns.astype(int) + 2
```

Comment: Very good point as `df.columns` is essentially a list.

Comment: df.columns is an `pd.Index` (or `pd.MultiIndex`), which will behave similarly to a `pd.Series` or `np.ndarray`- not a `list`

Comment: @CameronRiddell thanks for the correction. I responded to lazily without thinking :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use list comprehension to rename the columns adding two to each column name (I use `int` in case the column names are strings, but they look like they are integers):

```
data.columns = [int(col) + 2 for col in data.columns]
```

If columns are already integers, then:

```
data.columns = [col + 2 for col in data.columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can still use the `rename` method (which will let you chain other methods on top of this). Just pass a function intstead of a dictionary:

```
new_df = df.rename(columns=lambda c: int(c) + 2)
```

If your column names are already numeric, you can remove the `int()` and just do :

```
new_df = df.rename(columns=lambda c: c + 2)
```

And finally for the "why not- becaues we can" answer, you can ditch the lambda and use the `__add__` dunder method like so:

```
new_df = df.rename(columns=int(2).__add__)
```

Comment: This is useful as it can save a line of code or two as you can operate on the dataframe, rather than having to go to a new line to operate on the "pd.Index" or "pd.MultiIndex" :) +1

Answer (score 0):

You can use range:

```
df.columns = list(range(2,len(df.columns)+2))
```